# OSM Thunderforest API keys in QGIS3

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-3, quickmapservices

This question has been asked for QGIS 2 and it was poorly answered.

I have my API key from Thunderforest for accessing the OSM maps. I am trying to use the 'OSM TF outdoors' map. It requires an API key. But I have no idea where to put the url that contains my API key. The options that existed in QGIS 2 are either not there, or the answers are too vague to properly lead me to where I need to be.

I obtained the Thunderforest map through QuickMapServices

Does anyone know where to place OSM TF API keys in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on an example at thunderforest.com use `https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>`.

You can add XYZ-Tiles to QGIS via Browser -> XYZ-Tiles -> New Connection

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer was more straight forward and worked just fine so I changed the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use QuickMapServices

1) go to Web -> QuickMapServices -> Settings

[image]

2) add/edit/remove -> create service from existing (3.a) or create new service (3.b)

[image]

3.a) If you chose create service from existing choose the one you want to edit.

[image]

3.b) If you create a new service choose TMS as Type

[image]

4) in TMS tab edit the url and insert your api key

[image]